# Format two columns width using printf

Tags: bash, awk, printf, alignment

I have a file with two columns like this:

```
73697695 1111111100110100211010101100000110100111  
73697715 0100001010100022000020000000000200200000  
73698148  0000000000200000000200220001100100010111  
73698210 1111111211011012001011000001111000001110  
73698229 1111111100110111110020101000000111210011  
736985237658373533  0000000110100011101010000001100100100000  
73698858 1111111210010011101010000001100100100111  
73698887 2222222200020000202000000010001100110000  
73699163 2222222200020100110110211100000100100100  
7369929986423  2222222200020100110110211100000011110111
```

I am trying to create a bash file to format its columns. First I need to find the maximum length of the first column. So, I did this:

```
lengthID=$(awk '{ if (length($1) > max) max = length($1) } END { print max }' file)
```

After that I would like to apply that "lengthID" to such file to align the first column to the right based on the "lengthID". The second column must be align to the left. I tried use the following command line, but it did not work.

```
awk '{printf("%"lengthID"s%1s%" "s\n",$1," ",$2)}' file > temp && mv temp file
```

I know that the maximum length is 18 (lengthID = 18). So, the following command would work:

```
awk '{printf("%18s%1s%" "s\n",$1," ",$2)}' file > temp && mv temp file
```

And I would get a file like this (exactly what I need). However, I'd like to automatically find such length and use it.

```
          73697695 1111111100110100211010101100000110100111
          73697715 0100001010100022000020000000000200200000
          73698148 0000000000200000000200220001100100010111
          73698210 1111111211011012001011000001111000001110
          73698229 1111111100110111110020101000000111210011
736985230909090909 0000000110100011101010000001100100100000
          73698858 1111111210010011101010000001100100100111
          73698887 2222222200020000202000000010001100110000
          73699163 2222222200020100110110211100000100100100
     7369929986423 2222222200020100110110211100000011110111
```

Does anyone know a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: `cut -d' ' -f1 file | wc -L` will give you the max length of field 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c=length($1); w=(w>c?w:c); next} {printf "%*s %s\n", w, $1, $2}' file file
          73697695 1111111100110100211010101100000110100111
          73697715 0100001010100022000020000000000200200000
          73698148 0000000000200000000200220001100100010111
          73698210 1111111211011012001011000001111000001110
          73698229 1111111100110111110020101000000111210011
736985237658373533 0000000110100011101010000001100100100000
          73698858 1111111210010011101010000001100100100111
          73698887 2222222200020000202000000010001100110000
          73699163 2222222200020100110110211100000100100100
     7369929986423 2222222200020100110110211100000011110111
```

You sure you can't just use `column -t file` though?

```
$ column -t file
73697695            1111111100110100211010101100000110100111
73697715            0100001010100022000020000000000200200000
73698148            0000000000200000000200220001100100010111
73698210            1111111211011012001011000001111000001110
73698229            1111111100110111110020101000000111210011
736985237658373533  0000000110100011101010000001100100100000
73698858            1111111210010011101010000001100100100111
73698887            2222222200020000202000000010001100110000
73699163            2222222200020100110110211100000100100100
7369929986423       2222222200020100110110211100000011110111
```

The alignments different but if all you need are visual columns maybe that's OK.

Comment: That is great. Thank you.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the magic here is `%*s` in the printf which means that you provide the width component as a parameter as well as the string.